# Differentiability of $\cos^{-1}(1-x^2)$ and $\cos^{-1}(1-x^4)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

**Q1:** Determine if $f_1(x)=\cos^{-1}(1-x^2),\;\;x\in(-1,1),\;$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

**Working:**

Using the chain rule, $$f_1^{'}(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)^2}}\cdot (-2x) = \dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}} = \dfrac{2x}{|x|\sqrt{2-x^2}}.$$

At $x=0$, this is undefined. But I don't think this proves that $f_1$ is not differentiable at $0:\;$ the chain rule relies on the $cos^{-1}$ function being differentiable at $1 \;\;(= (1-x^2) |_{x=0})$, which it isn't, and this means it can't be legitimately used here.

I've tried working from the definition of the derivative but that gives a difficult limit to evaluate.

Plotting $f_1(x)$ shows a cusp point at $x=0$ so it looks non-differentiable there but how should we prove it properly?

$\\$

**Q2:** Determine if $f_2(x)=\cos^{-1}(1-x^4),\;\;x\in(-1,1),\;$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

**Working:**

Using the chain rule, $$f_2^{'}(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^4)^2}}\cdot (-4x^3) = \dfrac{4x^3}{\sqrt{2x^4-x^8}} = \dfrac{4x^3}{x^2\sqrt{2-x^4}}.$$

Again this is undefined for $x=0$, though the legitimacy of the chain rule is doubtful as in the above case.

However, the graph of $f_2(x)$ has no cusp point at $x=0$ and it looks differentiable there.

Using the definition for the derivative at $0$:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f_2(0+h) - f_2(0)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos^{-1}(1-h^4) - \cos^{-1}(1)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos^{-1}(1-h^4)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{4h^3}{h^2\sqrt{2-h^4}} \qquad\text{by l'Hopital's rule} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{4h}{\sqrt{2-h^4}} \qquad\text{can cancel since $h\neq 0$} \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

This indicates that $f_2$ is differentiable at $0$ and its derivative there is $0$ (agreeing with the plot). Is this correct? And is it wrong to use the chain rule for the reasons given above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reasoning is correct, and the limits to calculate the right and left derivatives of the first function in $x=0$ are not so different from the one used in the second function:
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f_1(0+h) - f_1(0)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos^{-1}(1-h^2) - \cos^{-1}(1)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\cos^{-1}(1-h^2)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{2h}{|h|\sqrt{2-h^2}} \qquad\text{by l'Hopital's rule} \\
&= \sqrt{2}\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{h}{|h|}
\end{align}
and this limit is $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$ depending on the direction.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! I tried something like that but gave up when it turned out the limit didn't exist (because the two one-sided limits are unequal) - and because I'd used l'Hopital that made the answer inconclusive on the original limit.

I should have considered it as two one-sided limits (like what you've done), because these do exist and that makes the use of l'Hopital's rule valid on each of them.

And we get the result that $f_1$ is not differentiable at $0$, which I'm sure is correct.